# How to make multiple where clause and get just only the first

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, collections, eloquent

I tried to accomplish a multiple where clause but failed. I want to check if the current Date of the user is equal to created_at and the second clause would be if the user has an entry by user id. I am working on a fitness app where the User can track the km he has run. And rather to create in a database table new entries just add them to the existing entries.
My Question is focused on the problem with the if clause because the variable `$hasUserEntries` is not equal to null but there is no entry in the database table. It is empty.

I tried instead of using `get()` I used `first()`. But the problem is that I wasn't able to use `Carbon::today()` or it was maybe that I use 3 values in the where clause which I need because I can't get the `created_at` date only the Date **YYYY-MM-DD**. At the `first()` Statement I used a hardcoded DateTime to check with `created_at` and it worked. But I think I must not explain why hardcode is not optimal.

I searched on Stackoverflow and find that most answers were about using `get()`. It is fine but why does my `else` get triggered because from my point of view the database is empty(Null) so the `if($hasUserEntries==null)`should be triggered.

```
public function add_km_to_progressbar(Request $request, TrackKM $trackKM)
{
    $track_dailies = new TrackDaily();
    $track_dailies->user_id = \Auth::user()->id;

    $amount_runned_km = $request->input('amount_runned_km');
    $amount_runned_km = (int)$amount_runned_km;

    $track_dailies->amount = (int)$amount_runned_km;

    $track_dailies->type = 1;

    $check_requirements = [
        'user_id'=>\Auth::user()->id,
        'created_at'=>'Carbon::today()'
    ];

    $hasUserEntries = DB::table('track_dailies')
                        ->where('user_id','=',\Auth::user())
                        ->where('created_at','>=',Carbon::today())
                        ->get();

    if ($hasUserEntries == null) {

        return dd('does not work');
    } else {

        return dd('does work');
    }
}
```

**Expected Result** should be the triggering of the if statement because if the database table is empty, the user id does not exist or the date of created_at is not the same as the current date then should be triggered `if($hasUserEntries==null)`. I want to create there a new row if this condition == null in the database.

**Actual Result** `if($hasUserEntries==null)` is true even though that the database table is empty. I think that the method `get()` has values saved that are not related to the database.

I hope that you can help me out.

Comment: Because `get()` is returning an empty collection, not `null`

Comment: `where('user_id','=',\Auth::user())` I think this should not work, the user() will not return simply the user_id but an object.

Answer (score 1):

i think what you should have done is checking to see if the record exist in the database before proceeding...

```
 $checkifuserExist= DB::table('track_dailies')->where('user_id','=',\Auth::user())->where('created_at','>=',Carbon::today())->count();
if($checkifuserExist>0)
{
   //proceed to query for fitness
}
else
{
  //do something else...
}
```

with this, it will not throw error!

Comment: since there is no entries in the db there is now way the null will work. you just have to check if the user exist first before proceeding with whatever conditions you want to achieve

Comment: just to improve your answer, you can just change your if condition to `if($checkIfuserExist)`. you have no need to add `>0` condition.

Comment: But it does not solve it. I check for null because if the user has a row for the special date (created_at == current_data) then instead of adding a new row to the database it should update the value of amount. If I use your code it does not solve it and i got the same problem.If I am not clear pls ask me.

Comment: what that code does is to first check if user exists in the database, if it does exists do the needful. let me show some code below

Answer (score 0):

Try this if case intead:

```
if (is_empty($hasUserEntries))
```

Comment: ```is_empty``` does not exist from laravel

Answer (score 0):

```
$checkifuserExist= DB::table('track_dailies')->where('user_id','=',\Auth::user())->where('created_at','>=',Carbon::today())->count();
if($checkifuserExist>0)
{
   //if user really exists
     if( $hasUserEntries = DB::table('track_dailies')->where('user_id','=',\Auth::user())->where('created_at','>=',Carbon::today())->first())
       {
             //update the value of the amount
       }
      else{

           //insert new record

         }

}
else
{

  // if the user does not exist, do something else...
}
```

remember theres no way the record for user_id would be null because first there has to be record inside the db

Comment: what if he is not created then it will be null or not?

Comment: "It is fine but why does my else get triggered because from my point of view the database is empty(Null) so the if($hasUserEntries==null)should be triggered."  the ($hasUserEntries==null) cannot be triggered with null because no record exists in the db. you need to first check the existence of record before checking for the existence of date

Comment: Oh ok i will try it out thank for the kind explanation

Comment: it will not be null. it will be null when there is record and a particular field has no record but null. ex. id: string, username:string, fname: null. id:-1, username:-john, fname:-null